# input to have replaced characters on typing issue?

Tags: javascript

There is an issue in the following fiddle link as it shows the characters which are typed first and then it converts into the other characters,

So is there any way that the typed characters won't show first and directly the replaced characters will only show?

As it's ugly now :

**JS Fiddle Link :** https://jsfiddle.net/moxet/z73m771p/

```js
$("#pashto").keyup(function(event) { 
    var car = $(this).val(); 
    car = car.replace("a", "ا");
    car = car.replace("A", "آ");
    car = car.replace("b", "ب");
    car = car.replace("B", "");
    car = car.replace("c", "چ");
    car = car.replace("C", "ث");
    car = car.replace("d", "د");
    car = car.replace("D", "ډ");
    car = car.replace("e", "ع");
    car = car.replace("E", "ږ");
    car = car.replace("f", "ف");
    car = car.replace("F", "");
    car = car.replace("g", "ګ");
    car = car.replace("G", "غ");
    car = car.replace("h", "ح");
    car = car.replace("H", "ځ");
    car = car.replace("i", "ي");
    car = car.replace("I", "ې");
    car = car.replace("j", "ج");
    car = car.replace("J", "ض");
    car = car.replace("k", "ک");
    car = car.replace("K", "خ");
    car = car.replace("l", "ل");
    car = car.replace("L", "");
    car = car.replace("m", "م");
    car = car.replace("M", "");
    car = car.replace("n", "ن");
    car = car.replace("N", "ڼ");
    car = car.replace("o", "ه");
    car = car.replace("O", "ۀ");
    car = car.replace("p", "پ");
    car = car.replace("P", "څ");
    car = car.replace("q", "ق");
    car = car.replace("Q", "ښ");
    car = car.replace("r", "ر");
    car = car.replace("R", "ړ");
    car = car.replace("s", "س");
    car = car.replace("S", "ص");
    car = car.replace("t", "ت");
    car = car.replace("T", "ټ");
    car = car.replace("u", "ئ");
    car = car.replace("U", "ۍ");
    car = car.replace("v", "ط");
    car = car.replace("V", "ظ");
    car = car.replace("w", "و");
    car = car.replace("W", "ؤ");
    car = car.replace("x", "ش");
    car = car.replace("X", "ژ");
    car = car.replace("y", "ے");
    car = car.replace("Y", "ی");
    car = car.replace("z", "ز");
    car = car.replace("Z", "ذ");
    car = car.replace("?", "؟");
    car = car.replace(";", "؛");
    car = car.replace("0", "۰");
    car = car.replace("1", "۱");
    car = car.replace("2", "۲");
    car = car.replace("3", "۳");
    car = car.replace("4", "۴");
    car = car.replace("5", "۵");
    car = car.replace("6", "۶");
    car = car.replace("7", "۷");
    car = car.replace("8", "۸");
    car = car.replace("9", "۹");
    $(this).val(car);
   });
```

```css
#pashto
{
    direction:rtl;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:5px;   
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="pashto" />
```

Comment: You can capture `keyDown` event and check the keyCode and process accordingly

Comment: [Why don't you use expressions instead of writing manually](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of `keyup` event is not really good in this case because the `keyup` is trigger, like the name says, on key up––after the letter is inserted and becomes visible in the textbox.

Use the `input` event. This will catch other events (such as paste, cut, delete using the mouse etc):

```
$("#pashto").on("input", function(event) { 
  ...
});
```

Another problem is that the keyup does not catch mouse text paste. So, if you copy `a` and right click and paste the text in your input, it won't get replaced correctly. The `input` event is triggered whenever the value is changed in the input.

Also, you can change the code, so it will look much better:

```js
var replacements = [
    ["a", "ا"], ["A", "آ"], ["b", "ب"], ["B", ""], ["c", "چ"],
    ["C", "ث"], ["d", "د"], ["D", "ډ"], ["e", "ع"], ["E", "ږ"],
    ["f", "ف"], ["F", ""], ["g", "ګ"], ["G", "غ"], ["h", "ح"],
    ["H", "ځ"], ["i", "ي"], ["I", "ې"], ["j", "ج"], ["J", "ض"],
    ["k", "ک"], ["K", "خ"], ["l", "ل"], ["L", ""], ["m", "م"],
    ["M", ""], ["n", "ن"], ["N", "ڼ"], ["o", "ه"], ["O", "ۀ"],
    ["p", "پ"], ["P", "څ"], ["q", "ق"], ["Q", "ښ"], ["r", "ر"],
    ["R", "ړ"], ["s", "س"], ["S", "ص"], ["t", "ت"], ["T", "ټ"],
    ["u", "ئ"], ["U", "ۍ"], ["v", "ط"], ["V", "ظ"], ["w", "و"],
    ["W", "ؤ"], ["x", "ش"], ["X", "ژ"], ["y", "ے"], ["Y", "ی"],
    ["z", "ز"], ["Z", "ذ"], ["?", "؟"], [";", "؛"], ["0", "۰"],
    ["1", "۱"], ["2", "۲"], ["3", "۳"], ["4", "۴"], ["5", "۵"],
    ["6", "۶"], ["7", "۷"], ["8", "۸"], ["9", "۹"]
].map(function (c) {
    // Escape the special characters
    var escaped = c[0].replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
    
    // And then convert into regular expression
    c[0] = new RegExp(escaped, "g");
    return c;
});

$("#pashto").on("input", function(event) {
    var car = $(this).val();
    
    // Now, simply replace by regular expressions
    replacements.forEach(function (c) {
        car = car.replace(c[0], c[1]);
    });
    $(this).val(car);
});
```

```css
#pashto {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="pashto" />
```

Comment: Also there is an another issue which is that after typing something in the input one cannot modify it by going through cursor to the other characters, Can you check that please? The cursor always goes to the end when you try to move it from the last location to the back characters.

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai I'd say to ask a new question for that. That's a very trick one, btw. You have to set the cursor position and to store it in a variable.

Comment: Here is the link to the new question then : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44301625/input-rtl-text-on-change-cursor-issue

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#pashto").keydown(function(event) { 
    var car = $(this).val(); 
    car = car.replace("a", "ا");
    car = car.replace("A", "آ");
    car = car.replace("b", "ب");
    car = car.replace("B", "");
    car = car.replace("c", "چ");
    car = car.replace("C", "ث");
    car = car.replace("d", "د");
    car = car.replace("D", "ډ");
    car = car.replace("e", "ع");
    car = car.replace("E", "ږ");
    car = car.replace("f", "ف");
    car = car.replace("F", "");
    car = car.replace("g", "ګ");
    car = car.replace("G", "غ");
    car = car.replace("h", "ح");
    car = car.replace("H", "ځ");
    car = car.replace("i", "ي");
    car = car.replace("I", "ې");
    car = car.replace("j", "ج");
    car = car.replace("J", "ض");
    car = car.replace("k", "ک");
    car = car.replace("K", "خ");
    car = car.replace("l", "ل");
    car = car.replace("L", "");
    car = car.replace("m", "م");
    car = car.replace("M", "");
    car = car.replace("n", "ن");
    car = car.replace("N", "ڼ");
    car = car.replace("o", "ه");
    car = car.replace("O", "ۀ");
    car = car.replace("p", "پ");
    car = car.replace("P", "څ");
    car = car.replace("q", "ق");
    car = car.replace("Q", "ښ");
    car = car.replace("r", "ر");
    car = car.replace("R", "ړ");
    car = car.replace("s", "س");
    car = car.replace("S", "ص");
    car = car.replace("t", "ت");
    car = car.replace("T", "ټ");
    car = car.replace("u", "ئ");
    car = car.replace("U", "ۍ");
    car = car.replace("v", "ط");
    car = car.replace("V", "ظ");
    car = car.replace("w", "و");
    car = car.replace("W", "ؤ");
    car = car.replace("x", "ش");
    car = car.replace("X", "ژ");
    car = car.replace("y", "ے");
    car = car.replace("Y", "ی");
    car = car.replace("z", "ز");
    car = car.replace("Z", "ذ");
    car = car.replace("?", "؟");
    car = car.replace(";", "؛");
    car = car.replace("0", "۰");
    car = car.replace("1", "۱");
    car = car.replace("2", "۲");
    car = car.replace("3", "۳");
    car = car.replace("4", "۴");
    car = car.replace("5", "۵");
    car = car.replace("6", "۶");
    car = car.replace("7", "۷");
    car = car.replace("8", "۸");
    car = car.replace("9", "۹");
    $(this).val(car);
   });
```

Comment: It doesn't solve a problem, English letters still appear.