# input rtl text on change cursor issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue in the following JS Fiddle snippet when someone types something in the input and then when he wants to modify it by going to backward typed characters so after pressing backspace i.e removing the character so the cursor automtically goes to the end of the input from the current position of the input.

Normally it wouldn't happen like that right?

So what would be causing this & is there anyway to fix this?

**JS Fiddle Link :** https://jsfiddle.net/5yrqsxa7/

```js
var replacements = [
    ["a", "ا"], ["A", "آ"], ["b", "ب"], ["B", ""], ["c", "چ"],
    ["C", "ث"], ["d", "د"], ["D", "ډ"], ["e", "ع"], ["E", "ږ"],
    ["f", "ف"], ["F", ""], ["g", "ګ"], ["G", "غ"], ["h", "ح"],
    ["H", "ځ"], ["i", "ي"], ["I", "ې"], ["j", "ج"], ["J", "ض"],
    ["k", "ک"], ["K", "خ"], ["l", "ل"], ["L", ""], ["m", "م"],
    ["M", ""], ["n", "ن"], ["N", "ڼ"], ["o", "ه"], ["O", "ۀ"],
    ["p", "پ"], ["P", "څ"], ["q", "ق"], ["Q", "ښ"], ["r", "ر"],
    ["R", "ړ"], ["s", "س"], ["S", "ص"], ["t", "ت"], ["T", "ټ"],
    ["u", "ئ"], ["U", "ۍ"], ["v", "ط"], ["V", "ظ"], ["w", "و"],
    ["W", "ؤ"], ["x", "ش"], ["X", "ژ"], ["y", "ے"], ["Y", "ی"],
    ["z", "ز"], ["Z", "ذ"], ["?", "؟"], [";", "؛"], ["0", "۰"],
    ["1", "۱"], ["2", "۲"], ["3", "۳"], ["4", "۴"], ["5", "۵"],
    ["6", "۶"], ["7", "۷"], ["8", "۸"], ["9", "۹"]
].map(function (c) {
    // Escape the special characters
    var escaped = c[0].replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
    
    // And then convert into regular expression
    c[0] = new RegExp(escaped, "g");
    return c;
});

$("#pashto").on("input", function(event) {
    var car = $(this).val();
    
    // Now, simply replace by regular expressions
    replacements.forEach(function (c) {
        car = car.replace(c[0], c[1]);
    });
    $(this).val(car);
});
```

```css
#pashto {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="pashto" />
```

Comment: The cursor goes to the end of input because you are replacing the input value, it's quite normal!

Comment: @chsdk : How it should stay at the position and not go to the end? I would say that's an issue isn't it because in ltr text the cursor stays at the position when someone press backspace?

Comment: I think it won't be easy to do it with your current code, you need to change the whole logic.

Comment: @chsdk : It's the new version of this old script as : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300868/input-to-have-replaced-characters-on-typing-issue